# How to modify values inside a file

Tags: arduino-uno, sd-card, esp32

I am writing a wav file to an SD card on a ESP32 and that requires that every time I append data to the the end of the file I modify the header to set the right size in some fields.

I cannot find how to replace a value inside a file, I tried to write the new values with the seek function but unless I'm missing something looks like this deletes everything after the new value added.

I do not want to create a new file and to delete the old one as I will storing potentially large wav files and looks like wasting resources.

Is there a way to overwrite one value inside a file. I'm using **SDlib** but I'm open to others too.

Here the code I use to create the file and to update it:

```
#include "WavFileWriter.h"

void WavFileWriter::createFile(char const* filename, WavFileHeader* wavFileHeader)
{
  byte headerBuffer[44];
  wavFileHeader->getHeaderData(headerBuffer);
  File file = SD.open(filename, FILE_WRITE);
  file.write(headerBuffer, 44);
  file.close();
}

void WavFileWriter::appendData(char const* filename, WavFileHeader* wavFileHeader, byte* data, int dataLength)
{
  File file = SD.open(filename, FILE_WRITE);
  file.write(data, dataLength);

  byte headerBuffer[44];
  wavFileHeader->setFileSize(file.size());
  wavFileHeader->getHeaderData(headerBuffer);

  file.seek(0);
  file.write(headerBuffer, 44);
  file.close();
}
```

After calling appendData I end up with a file with just the header size (with the right header for a file with data but the data is gone).

Comment: why do you need to store the sound data in `wav` format?

Comment: can you identify the position of the sector on the SD card where the header is stored, keep a copy of it in RAM, keep this copy updated and write it to SD from time to time?

Comment: just store the raw data ... if you need a wav file then use something like Audacity to convert raw to wav

Comment: show your code.

Comment: added the code. I should have done from the beginning, my bad.

Comment: issue: if I have an fixed size file (8MB in my case), and I seek somewhere
an the file and do a write, the file size is truncated to the end of the block that I write. I am emulating a disk using a file and trying to write "sector data"
at various locations. Read using the same strategy works fine, but the writes destroy any data after the sector I write by truncating the file size. // running on an ESP32 using arduino IDE 1.8.13 environment // start with a file called CPM000.DSK on an SD card that is 256*64*512 bytes #include "FS.h" // file system support #include "SD_MMC.h" // uSD card suppo

Answer (score 1):

The `FILE_WRITE` in SD library is 'append' (for historical reasons)

```
#define FILE_WRITE (O_READ | O_WRITE | O_CREAT | O_APPEND)
```

so use

```
 File file = SD.open(filename, O_WRITE);
```

Comment: Looks like the ESP32 uses a different library and the definitions are different: #define FILE_READ       "r"
#define FILE_WRITE      "w"
#define FILE_APPEND     "a"

Comment: Should I use SPIFFS instead of SD?

Answer (score 0):

SD.seek() is the API you're looking for.  It allow you to position the read/write pointer within a file.   In standard C++ the fseek() API is used.

Comment: OP is using seek()

Comment: I added the code so you can see if this is the expected usage.

Comment: It looks like you're not seek'ing to the end of the file when you attempt to append data.  Try:  file.seek(file.size()) between the SD.open() and file.write() in the WavFileWriter::appendData() method.